# MySQL Function Trigger creation

Tags: mysql, function, triggers, loaddata, str-to-date

**I need to create a Function in Mysql that needs to have 2 parameters type TEXT that needs to format the date and time in MySQL format for all the lines from a .txt file.
EX from the .txt file:
"19:01:31";"11.38.35";"Kresser";"Lynn";"Credit";"-700";"Hawai"

**then I need to create a Trigger before insert that at each insert calls the Function previously created, with the parameters date and time that are inserted in the table.

I tried the following but without success:

```
CREATE FUNCTION data_corecta(data TEXT,ora TEXT)
    RETURNS DATETIME
    DETERMINISTIC 
    COMMENT 'Receives date, time in a format and returns datetime in the corect format MySql'
BEGIN
    DECLARE dataora DATETIME; 
    SET data=str_to_date('19:01:31','%y:%m:%d');
    SET ora=str_to_date('11.38.35','%H.%i.%s');
    SET dataora=concat(data,' ',ora);
    RETURN dataora;
END /
delimiter ;


DROP TRIGGER if exists TR_DATA;
            
   DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER tr_data 
    BEFORE INSERT ON Tabela_veche
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    CALL data_corecta();
    INSERT INTO tabela_veche (fulldate)
        VALUES (concat(data,' ',ora));       
END //
delimiter ;

load data infile 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\fisier.txt' 
    into table Tabela_veche 
    character set latin1
    fields terminated by ';'
    optionally enclosed by '"'
    lines terminated by '\r\n'
    (data,ora,nume,prenume,descriere,valoare,locatia,fulldate);
```

Can you please correct it or let me know what is wrong?

Thank you, Denisa

Comment: You cannot action the table which fired the trigger in the trigger, in a before insert trigger you can adjust NEW. values.

Comment: And what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: Manual has examples https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html